# Cannot resolve symbol Mock or InjectMocks

Tags: java, intellij-idea, mockito

I am using Intellij, and my external dependencies folder show I am using mockito-all-1.10.19.jar.

I am using this simple Mockito example.

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AuditUnitTests {

    @Mock
    AuditTwo two;

    @InjectMocks
    AuditOne one;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        one.sayHelloFilter("Saurav");
        one.sayHelloFilter("Dravid");
        one.sayHelloFilter("Sachin");
        verify(two, times(2)).sayHello();
    }
}
```

However my Intellij complains that It cannot resolve Mock and InjectMocks annotations. How can I resolve it ?

Note:
I am using Ivy for dependency management:

```
   <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.12" conf="test"/>
    <dependency org="org.mockito" name="mockito-all" rev="1.10.19" conf="test"/>
```

Comment: Are you using maven? Could you show us your mockito dependencies?

Comment: updated edits above

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your static import is not sufficent. You have to add following additional imports.

```
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
```